# Run python program in background

Tags: python, macos

I have written a Python program that checks product prices and sends me an email whenever the price drops. It checks for the price once a day and I would like to make this program run in the background. What is the best way to do this?

I have seen a lot about just putting an `&` behind the command, something like: `python myscript &` but I'm wondering what will happen if I do so and shut down my computer. Will it start running again when I  startup my computer? And of course how to stop it once it starts running. I am using a MacBook.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, it won't start running again.

Comment: What are your requirements? Do you just want to do this on macOS?

Comment: You probably want to use `cron`. Copy your script in `/etc/cron.daily/`

Comment: I do not have the cron.daily map (or i just cannot find it). Do I have to download something?

Comment: ok, it seems that on MacOS, cron has been replaced by launchd, as described here...: https://superuser.com/questions/126907/how-can-i-get-a-script-to-run-every-day-on-mac-os-x

Answer (score 0):

The preferred way to set up a recurring job on macOS is to use a launch agent.

1. Create a launch agent property list file in `~/Library/LaunchAgents/`

   Example: `seancedric.myscript.plist`
2. The plist file should look something like the following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>[label for your launch agent. ex: seancedric.myscript]</string>

    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
      <string>[absolute path to your script. ex: /Users/seancedric/bin/myscript]</string>
      <string>[any arguments, each as a <string> xml element]</string>
    </array>

    <key>Nice</key>
    <integer>1</integer>

    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>[seconds: 60]</integer>

    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>

    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>[absolute path to log file]</string>

    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>[absolute path to log file]</string>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

For more see **Creating Launch Daemons and Agents**:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html

Answer (score 0):

I would do it a bit different. If your plans are to convert your .py (or.pyw) file to an executable file (.exe) later than you can do it with the command "pyinstaller -w yourfilename". Here is a youtube video where someone explains it (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lOIJIk_maO4). But I do not know if this works for mac the same way